# How to undo last local commits in Git and go back to the remote state?

Tags: git, merge, git-remote, revert

I merged a remote branch into my local repo and it created 26 local commits.

Now, I want to revert this merge, but it think that it is quite boring and error-sensitive to revert the commits 1 by 1 or seek for the last commit of the remote version to revert to it.

I went through the post [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git) which is very interesting with its answers, but I didn't found any simple way to do my local revert.

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Git Log & Git Reset

```
git log
```

this will give you the commit id with message through which you can identify your commit id.

use the commit id to then reset back.

```
git reset <commit-id>
```

if you permanently want to go back to that commit. you can use the following.

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

Comment: You can reset to a branch tip, so you can do `git reset --hard origin/master` to reset back to whatever master was at on your origin remote last time you talked to that remote.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it may not be valid to assume that origin/master would have the same commit id as the OP hasn't mentioned that origin/master and the local branch was in sync.

Comment: ok, but I was searching for a solution without using the commid ids, and as I merge **into** my local branch, my purpose is to go back to the remote state of this exact branch. So thanks to @Lasse V. Karlsen @"Lasse V. Karlsen"

Comment: I found another "tricky" solution which seems close to @Lasse V. Karlsen one (see my own answer), but the Lasse one is far simpler ! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I tried one or two things and this one is a little bit dirty, but it is simple and seems to work :

- checkout to another branch (create one if none) : `git checkout -b tempo`
- remove the bad local branch : `git branch -D dirty_one`
- recreate the local branch synchronized with remote one : `git checkout -b dirty_one origin/dirty_one`

and that's all.

The dirty thing I think is that the bad local commits are still in the local repo, but the branch don't know them so they may remain hidden.

If I redo my merge (which I have done in fact), the merge just work well, but I don't know exactly how (that the dirty part ...)